# Why do I sometimes get Last Exception Backtrace(0) error when swift scrollToRow?

Tags: swift

I got a Last Exception Backtrace (0) error in the code below

but i couldn't reproduce the error

Can you possibly prevent the Last Exception Backtrace (0) error?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(
        row: self.numberOfRows(inSection:  self.numberOfSections-1) - 1,
         section: self.numberOfSections - 1)
    if self.hasRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath) {
        self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: isAnimated) // here Error!!
    }
}
```